# Setting a date and hour in Oracle

Tags: oracle, date, datetime

am trying to get ALL data from an oracle table. I tried with this sentences in the WHERE clause.

```
date between to_date(sysdate-1) and to_date(sysdate);
date between (current_date-1) and (current_date);
date BETWEEN (TO_CHAR(SYSDATE-1,'DD-MON-YY')) AND (TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'DD-MON-YY'));
```

Just to compare the results, I executed the query with this code:

```
date between to_date('08/04/2015 00:00:00.00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss.ff' ) and
to_date('09/04/2015 00:00:00.00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss.ff' )
```

I am totally sure this query gives me the right set of data that I am looking for, but this result is totally different to the ones that I've got with the first two examples and even the four results are different between them.

This query is executed automatically after midnight and I can update the date manually, so my question is how can I get the same result that I've got when I specified directly that I needed ALL the registers from the previous day (from 00:00 am to 12:00 pm).

Regards

Comment: TRUNC function takes off the time part of a DATE field. Try: date between trunc(sysdate)-1 and trunc(sysdate); Also, don't use to_date on a date format, it's redundant and doesn't really do anything.

Comment: That's not true; it does do something. It makes an implicit conversion from DATE to string and then back to DATE again.

Comment: So date >= trunc(sysdate-1) and date <  trunc(sysdate) is the way I should execute this query?, I mean, this is the condition that gives me ONLY the results of the previos day (24 hours: 00-00-00 to 24-00-00).

Answer (score 5):

Doing `TO_DATE()` on something that's already a `DATE` datatype is a big no-no. You're relying on implicit conversions from a `DATE` to a string and then back to a `DATE`, which might cause unintended results. Far better to use something that explicitly does what you want it to do, eg. `TRUNC()`.

Also, `BETWEEN` is inclusive - if you're after everything that happened yesterday **including** today at midnight, then you're fine to use `BETWEEN`.

If you want everything that happened yesterday **excluding** midnight today, then you'd be best off doing something like:

```
...
and date_col >= trunc(sysdate -1)
and date_col < trunc(sysdate)
...
```

Don't forget that `DATE` includes a time value, so if you're wanting everything across a single day, you have to remember to truncate the dates to midnight (e.g. `trunc(sysdate)`)

Comment: Thanks a lot Boneist, this is the condition that is given me the same result that I've got with the test where I used the explicit day.

Comment: I agree with @Boneist, `TO_DATE` on a `DATE` column will force Oracle to:

First convert it into string
Then convert it back to DATE
based on the locale-specific NLS settings. It is just a bug in the code.